# Multiple joins on the same table with counting in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

I have an elementary question about SQL query with joining the same table twice. It sounds very simple, but I have some troubles with it. I hope, anyone can help me with this issue :)

I have two little tables: "peoples" (columns: id, name, ...) and "likes" (id, who, whom). People may set the "likes" to each other. The relationship is many to many.
I want get the table with peoples likes: count of received "likes", delivered and count of mutual likes.
All is correctly, when I use only one join. But for two joins (or more) MySQL combine all rows (as expected) and I get wrong values in counts. I don't know, how I must use count/sum/group-by operators in this case:( I would like to do this without subqueries in one query.

I used a query like this:

```
SELECT *, count(l1.whom), count(l2.whom)
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN likes l1 ON l1.who = p.id
LEFT JOIN likes l2 ON l2.whom = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

```
SELECT p.id, name, 
   count(lwho.who) delivered_likes, 
   count(lwhom.whom) received_likes, 
   count(lmut.who) mutual_likes
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN likes AS lwho ON p.id = lwho.who
LEFT JOIN likes AS lwhom ON lwhom.id = lwho.id
LEFT JOIN likes AS lmut ON lwhom.who = lmut.whom AND lwhom.whom = lmut.who
GROUP BY p.id;
```

But it's calculated the counts of likes incorrect.

It's issue just for training and performance is not important, but I guess, that three joins in my last query is too much. Can I do it using 2 joins?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Your join looks fine.  But, you should be sure to group by all columns in your query that you aren't aggregating.You aren't grouping by `name` in your second query.  I can't stand that MySQL allows this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I surmise that there is a 1:N relationship between `people` and `likes`.

One problem with your second query, as far as I can tell, is that the `lwhom` correlation of `likes` is joined to `lwho` via `id=id`. Basically `lwhom` *is* `lwho`. I'd recommend changing the ON clause for this correlation from `lwhom.id = lwho.id` to `p.id = lwhom.whom`.

The counts will still be affected by the JOINs, however. Supposing that you have an ID column in the `likes` table, though, you could then have each `COUNT` tally the distinct Like IDs per person – if not, consider just using `COUNT(DISTINCT correlation.*)` instead.

Digressions aside, the following should hopefully work:

```
SELECT p.id, name, 
   count(distinct lwho.id) delivered_likes, 
   count(distinct lwhom.id) received_likes, 
   count(distinct lmut.id) mutual_likes
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN likes AS lwho ON p.id = lwho.who
LEFT JOIN likes AS lwhom ON p.id = lwhom.whom
LEFT JOIN likes AS lmut ON lwhom.who = lmut.whom AND lwhom.whom = lmut.who
GROUP BY p.id,p.name;
```

I have an SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61b3e/1/0).

Comment: Hey, Adam.

Thanks a lot for your answer and the example. It works for me too. It helped me to understand my mistakes.
It should be careful with several joins and grouping:)

PS Of course, the relationship is a 1:N - one human and more likes. That's my sad mistake in description.